# How to show US states but not other countries' provinces

Tags: google-earth

I can check/uncheck `Layers -> Border and Labels ->  Borders -> 1st Level Admin Borders (States/Provinces)` (Names too):

- If checked, I see US states (California, etc.) which I want to see. But, I also see the subdivision of other countries, like the division of Israel into 6 provinces.
- If unchecked, I don't see US states.

Currently, I check/uncheck depending on whether I'm looking at the US or not, but that's annoying. Is there a way to see just US states? Or select which countries' states I want / don't want to see?

Comment: I am pretty sure its an all or nothing type of setting.